# convert raster to xyz without no data values

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I want to convert a geotif to an xyz-file by gdal_translate. However, when I use the following statement:

gdal_translate infile.tif outfile.xyz -of xyz

the nodata values are always within the xyz-file. I want only the xyz values of pixels where data is available...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
grep -v NaN xyz > xyz_without_nodata
```

You should define your nodata values, I assumed NaN here. You could try setting -a_nodata with "none" which means that you don't want that in the output, check here the details: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Comment: Thanks! This works, but isn't there a function within gdal (or other gis-package) that allows to export only the points with data?

Comment: you're welcome! I updated my answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: Instead of **-a_nodata None**                                  Try: **gdal_translate -of xyz -a_nodata Value infile.tif outfile.xyz** (Where "Value" is the value of the nodata point)

Comment: The above gdal_translate command did not work for me. It still outputs the missing data value converting from .asc file