# Obtaining the portion of upstream cell from taudem

Tags: taudem

In taudem I know that I can use [StreamNet](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/help53/StreamReachAndWatershed.html) function:

```
StreamNet -fel <felfile> -p <pfile> -ad8 <ad8file> -src <srcfile> -ord <ordfile> -tree <treefile> -coord<coordfile> -net <netfile> [ -netlyr netlayername] [ -o <outletfile>] [ -lyrname <layer name>] [ -lyrno <layer number>] -w <wfile> [ -sw]

pfile: Input D8 flow directions grid 'p'

srcfile: Input stream raster grid 'src'

ordfile: Output grid of channel network Strahler order 'ord'

ad8file: Input grid with D8 contributing area 'ad8'

felfile: Input pit filled elevation data grid 'fel'

treefile: Output textfile with list of links in channel network tree

coordfile: Output textfile with list of coordinates in channel network tree

outletfile: input outlets file (OGR readable dataset).This must contain a field named "id" that is

used to identify the links upstream of outlet points

layer name: OGR layer name if outlets are not the first layer in outletfile (optional)

layer number: OGR layer number if outlets are not the first layer in outletfile (optional)

Layer name and layer number should not both be specified.

wfile: Output grid of watershed identifiers 'w'

netfile: Output file (OGR writeable data set) of resultant channel network.

netlayername: layer name of netfile (Optional)
```

to obtain the streamline shape, by reading off the values in the output file `treefile` and `coordfile`.

**But what about obtaining, for each cell, the portion of upstream cells that contribute flow to it?**

I suspect that the answer lies somewhere in the command argument `wfile`( with the file extension `.tif`) and `netfile` ( with the extension `.shp`). But these are binary files, and I don't know how can I extract the information out.

Any idea?

**Note:** I am aware that `shape` and `tif` files can be opened by GIS suite, but that is not my purpose. I want to extract those information out because I want to be able to render them on my own choice of viewer, and maybe do some statistical analysis on it using statistical tools of my choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “ad8” raster defines the upstream contributing area (number of cells) for every cell in your input elevation model. The file, produced by TauDEM as a geoTiff, can be opened in any GIS suite.

Also note, the “netfile” output will be an Esri shapefile for your stream network, again readable in any GIS suite, including ArcGIS, Q-GIS, etc.

You can follow [convert raster to xyz without no data values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138580/convert-raster-to-xyz-without-no-data-values) to use GDAL to translate the output raster to a simple xyz text file.

Comment: I know that it can be opened in GIS software, but I want to extract those information out because I want to be able to render them on my own choice of viewer, and maybe do some statistical analysis on it using statistical tools of my choice

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138580/convert-raster-to-xyz-without-no-data-values

Comment: About the link, I don't understand how is it relevant to my question here-- in the link there seems to be only dealing with `x`, `y` and `z` coordinate, and nothing else, certainly nothing about other metadata like the contribution from upstream cells, no?

Comment: The xyz being spoken about in the link refer to converting a raster (like your contributing area tif) to a text file containing the coordinates for each raster cell (x,y) and that cell’s value (z). If you are looking for the most generic format for the contributing area data, this simple text file would be it. The contributing area information isn’t metadata, it IS the data associated with the ad8 contributing area raster.